# Loading Custom Objects to JavaFX Combobox from Mysql database

Tags: java, hibernate, javafx, combobox

I'm trying to load a list of objects from a mysql table to a javaFX Combobox using hibernate and dao pattern, here is my code :

Main.java

```
public class Main extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        BorderPane root = (BorderPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/Home.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,1600,900);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setTitle("Dentium");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setMaximized(true);

        primaryStage.show();

        Rectangle2D primScreenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
        primaryStage.setX((primScreenBounds.getWidth() - primaryStage.getWidth()) / 2);
        primaryStage.setY((primScreenBounds.getHeight() - primaryStage.getHeight()) / 4);

    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

OthersDaoImplementation

```
public class OthersDaoImp implements OthersDao {


@Override
public List<Others> getAllHealthAlerts() {

    List<Others> healthAlerts = new ArrayList<>();
    Transaction transaction = null;
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

    try
    {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        healthAlerts = session.createQuery("from Others").list();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
    catch (RuntimeException e)
    {
        if (transaction != null) {
            transaction.rollback();
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        session.flush();
        session.close();
    }
    return healthAlerts;
}
```

}

I'm getting this error, any help would be much appreciated.

```
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Hibernate: select others0_.id as id1_0_, others0_.healthAlert as        healthAl2_0_ from others others0_
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/D:/Programming/EclipseNeon/DentiumFx/bin/view/Home.fxml

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
at application.Main.start(Main.java:16)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.checkTransactionNeeded(SessionImpl.java:3450)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1418)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1414)
at dao.imp.OthersDaoImp.getAllHealthAlerts(OthersDaoImp.java:60)
at controller.PatientController.getHealthAlertsList(PatientController.java:31)
at controller.PatientController.initialize(PatientController.java:115)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
... 17 more
```

Comment: Which is line 60?

Comment: 'session.flush(); '  of    OthersDaoImp.getAllHealthAlerts();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Javadocs for `Session.flush()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#flush--)

> Force this session to flush. Must be called at the end of a unit of work, **before committing the transaction** and closing the session

So if you call `flush()`, you should do so in the `try` block, before calling `commit()`.

However, what `flush()` does is

> synchroniz[e] the underlying persistent store with persistable state held in memory

i.e. it updates the database with the current in-memory state. Since you haven't changed any persistent objects in memory in this transaction, I think this call is redundant anyway. You should be able to just remove this call.